# Is there a predefined QString function to replace UI control characters?

Tags: qt

Some characters in the text of a button / checkbox / label are treated as control characters, e.g. `&` for defined a character for the Alt-Modifier key (and I'm not 100% sure if there are more).

Is there a predefined function to escape those characters correctly like there is `QString::toHmtlEncoded()` for HTML?